# Carla Simulator Error on windows

Tags: python, nvidia-graphics-card

I have installed Carla Simulation on Windows 7 64-bit, but when I try to run it, I get an error and I don't know how to fix it.

I have searched on the internet but didn't find any solutions. Could you please help me solve this problem? 
[image: Photo of error.]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Open up the Epic Games Launcher
2. Click on the Library tab
3. Click on the yellow and black downward arrow beside Launch
4. Click on Options
5. Make sure that there is a check-mark beside 'Editor symbols for debugging'
6. Press Apply
```

Once you've done that, it should update the editor for you and this issue should go away. Please let us know if it does not.

Taken from [this](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/382003/you-do-not-have-any-debugging-symbols-required-to.html) source.

Comment: yes Dear , all of them has been selected but the error still , i dont know what should i do .